# Remove node and previous node if matched node is empty

Tags: xslt

It is possible to remove parent node and previous parent node if the matched node is empty?

Example:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p>Banana
        </p>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tbody>Not empty</tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <p>Apple
        </p>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

If `<table>-><tbody>` is empty I would like to remove `<table>` and previous `<div>` node.

Example output:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p>Banana
        </p>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tbody>Not empty</tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You're expected to show an attempt.  Hint: Add to the identity transform two templates that suppress (a) `div` elements followed by a `table` element that contains an empty `tbody` element and (b) such `table` elements themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no operation in XSLT to "remove" a node. A node is removed unless you actively copy it to the output. If the template rule that matches a node is empty (does nothing) then the node will effectively be removed. So you can write

```
<xsl:template match="div[following-sibling::*[1]
                        [self::table[not(string(tbody))]]]"/>
```

Which matches any div followed by a table with an empty `tbody`, and does nothing.

This assumes that your stylesheet is processing elements using a recursive-descent apply-templates operation in the normal way, and that this is the best-match rule for these nodes.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I can not edit your answer, but it has missing one right bracket at the end.

Comment: Edit applied, thanks